# Trying to capture an imageView then put it in a bmp

Tags: android, bitmap, screen-capture

I'm trying to capture an imageView and out it in a bmp. It currently works but, i am not able to make the captured imageView the correct size. This gives me a problem was black bar on the side of my imageView when it put the drawingcache as a bmp back into the imageview for display.

My code is like this:

> imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
>         Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView.getDrawingCache());

I tired doing :

```
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) dw, (int) dh,imageView.getDrawingCache());
```

but imageView.getDrawCache (BMP type) is not same type as Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888. I'm not sure how to tackle this specific problem. Any help would be nice.

Please read this question for more detail and screenshots.
[Black bars on the side of screen capture on imageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028587/black-bars-on-the-side-of-screen-capture-on-imageview)